# C++ Calling a templated function with a variable type

Tags: c++, templates

Imagine we have a function (that can not be modified) of this form:

```cpp
template <typename T>
Ptr<T> 
ObjectFactory::Create (void) const
{
  Ptr<Object> object = Create ();
  return object->GetObject<T> ();
}
```

The type of T is used internally for the method `GetObject<> ()`.

Then I want to have a second function that I don't to template that does something like:

```cpp
void install(...)
{
    Ptr<T> a = Create<T> ():
}
```

In the code above I used `<T>`,however I want the T to be a variable and not something that comes from a template.

Is there a way to do that?

Comment: No, template instantiation happens at compile time

Comment: *In the code above I used ,however I want the T to be a variable and not something that comes from a template.* Can you demonstrate that with some pseudo code?  It's unclear to me what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Sorry the `<T>` did not show. I want to be able to call `install` with the object type as a parameter and then pass that to `Create`. So basically I would like T to be the object type.

Comment: So you want something like `int foo; install(foo);` and then in `install` it uses `int` for `T`?

Comment: Well something like that yes. Maybe it does not make sense in C++.  What I am trying to do in my mock code is to cast one Base object to another object, I want my derived object to be the variable.

Comment: I ended up templating the install function. I can't really find another way.